# Error yas--advance-end-maybe-previous-fields with autoactivating yasnippets in latex environments in org mode

Tags: org-mode, latex, yasnippet

I get the error `yas--advance-end-maybe-previous-fields: Assertion failed: (memq field (yas--snippet-fields snippet))` in org mode when I use snippets that:

- do not contain $1 in the snippet
- use auto expansion within latex environments with `# condition: (and (texmathp) 'auto)`

I did not get the error

- autoactivating snippets outside of latex environments
- when the snippet had a $1
- when not autoacivating snippets in latex environments
- with similar snippets in latex documents instead of org documents

**Example** :

After test is expanded to tested using the snippet below, pressing a letter key results in the error mentioned before

```
    # -*- mode: snippet -*-
    # name: testSnippet
    # key: test
    # condition: (and (texmathp) 'auto)
    # --
    tested
```

Comment: also, what is a good way to suppress the assertion errors ?